# ID3 Artwork Tags from MP3 In Documents Directory iPhone Development

Tags: iphone, uiimage, mp3, id3, artwork

I have several MP3 files in the user's documents directory, and I want to be able to get and display the ID3 Artwork Tags. I have tried using NSURLAsset, but I am unsure how to convert that to a UIImage or a UIImageView!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the [AVAsset](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class:
For instance:

```
NSString *mp3Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"audio-file" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:mp3Path];

AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
for (NSString *format in [asset availableMetadataFormats]) {
    for (AVMetadataItem *item in [asset metadataForFormat:format]) {
        if ([[item commonKey] isEqualToString:@"artwork"]) {            
            NSData *data = [(NSDictionary *)[item value] objectForKey:@"data"];
            UIImageView *img = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]] autorelease];
            [self.view addSubview:img];
            continue;
        }
        NSLog(@"%@", item);
    }
}
NSLog(@"> Duration = %.2f seconds", CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration));
```